# error encountered (validattribute ) while running surf matlab code

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, matlab-cvst

This code produces error:

> validateattribute(I{'logical','unit8'.....

Please anyone can tell me why this is so..

```
I = imread('flowers.jpg');
I=im2double(I);
points = detectSURFFeatures(I);
imshow(I); hold on;
plot(points.selectStrongest(10));
```

Answer (score 0):

`detectSURFFeatures` takes grayscale images. If your image is RGB, you should call `rgb2gray` frist.

The error message should be telling you something to that effect.